# Check if element is in the fadeIn or fadeOut state ('action')

Tags: jquery

I need to stop(cancel) current .fadeIn(5000) and start the same fadeIn from the beginning, once a button is clicked (otherwise next fadeIn will start only after 5000). How can I check, if div is actively fading and how to can cancel it (I assume I could just .hide())?

Comment: I would still like a non-`.data` answer to this for unit testing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). You don't need to test if `fadeIn` is running, if it is not, `stop` has not effect.

You still have to hide it though. So it would be something like:

```
$('selector').stop(true).hide().fadeIn(5000);
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks for sharing. It produces a much better feel than waiting for the animation to play out!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `.hide()` to stop it from fading and instantly hide it.

If you need to detect that it is fading without stopping the fade, it gets more complicated.

The easiest way to detect it without changing it is to use `.data` to set a value on the element that shows that it is currently fading.

Then, if your `.fade` call, use a callback that removes that value, like this:

```
element.data('fading', true);
element.fade(5000, function() {
    $(this).data('fading', false);
});
```

You can then check if it is currently fading using:

```
if(element.data('fading'))
```

Comment: The trouble with just using `.hide()` is that it doesn't actually cancel the animation. So if OP wanted to hide it, then immediately begin a new fadeIn, the new one wouldn't start until the previous finished (even though you can't see it). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XUyLW/